# arc sin and sum of vectors

Tags: vectors

I'm trying to sum two vectors, and get the angle of the new vector.
I have two vectors, defined by their length and the angle they make with the X axis.
The formula I have for getting the length of the new vector:
$\sqrt{d_1^2+d_2^2+2d_1d_2 \cos(a_1-a_2)}$ where $d_1$ is the length of the first vector, $d_2$ is the length of the second vector, a1 is the angle the first vector makes with the $X$ axis, and $a_2$ is the angle the second vector makes with the $X$ axis.
And this is my equation for the angle:
$\arcsin(\frac{(d_2.size*\sin(d_2-d_1))}{d_3}) - a_1$ where $d_3$ is the length of the new vector in the formula above.
And this works, sometimes...
Sometimes I need to add 180 or something like that to get the right angle.
Now I have intuition, but if I try to program this into a computer, how do I know when I need to add 180 or not?

Thanks a lot to all helpers

Comment: Probably everything will go easier if you work in Cartesian coordinates. Let the two vectors be $x_1 = d_1\cos a_1, y_1 = d_1\sin a_1$ and $x_2 = d_2\cos a_2, y_2 = d_2\sin a_2$, then the new vector is $x_3 = x_1 + x_2, y_3 = y_1 + y_2$, and [its angle is $a_3 = \operatorname{atan2}(y_3, x_3)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Comment: The problem with $\arcsin$ is quadrant uncertainty and the same is true of $\arctan$ as well. $\arctan2$ is the surest way as pointed out by Rahul above

Comment: Alright, I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: hey try the answer. its great for the program aspect. rahul's answer is also great but it requires some changes in the input variables.

Answer (score 0):

ok . so you are successful in getting the resultant length. Now to get the direction of the two vectors.

first of all find the $x$ components and the $y$ components of the vectors.the $x$ component is
$$V_x=d_1\cos a_1+d_2\cos a_2$$
and $y$ component
$$V_y=d_1\sin a_1+d_2\sin a_2$$
then $$\theta=arctan\frac{V_y}{V_x}$$
now if $V_x>=0$ and $V_y>=0$ 
$$a_3=\theta$$
if $V_x<=0$ and $V_y>=0$ 
$$a_3=180-\theta$$
 $V_x<=0$ and $V_y<=0$ 
$$a_3=180+\theta$$
 if$V_x>=0$ and $V_y<=0$ 
$$a_3=-\theta$$